# Show total number of listings on job search page in cariera theme job manager

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

```html
function wpb_total_posts() {
 
$total = wp_count_posts( 'job_listing' )->publish;

return $total; 

}
```

I would like to know if there is any possible ways to show the total listings count on the job listing page of Cariera WordPress theme job manager.
I need to show the total listing count at the top of the page
Still i couldn't find any code perform this action...

Added this code to function.php

function wpb_total_posts() {

$total = wp_count_posts( 'job_listing' )->publish;

return $total;

}

add_shortcode('total_posts','wpb_total_posts');

after this added shortcode to display the count..

this will help to show the total job count from my cariera theme
but i didn't think it will change according to the job search option.

so, is there any other way to add listing count based on the displayed results

Comment: You mean the Cariera Wordpress theme ?

Comment: yes the same
https://themeforest.net/item/cariera-job-board-wordpress-theme/20167356?gclid=CjwKCAiA8ov_BRAoEiwAOZogwZEcqmmFk1JIOy9qunfXEDEWgeErbuoqknFZrKwl1KRy3lzvcINgkRoC22kQAvD_BwE